# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

Tags: r

I stuck in an otherwise straightforward code that uses the dplyr function. Below is the sample data, df. When I ran the code below, it shows error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

This is the sample data.

```
Date       Ret1
1/1/2010    41.27974
4/1/2010    10.15308
7/1/2010    8.126499
10/1/2010   57.53005
1/1/2011    11.99968
4/1/2011    -19.79116
7/1/2011    2.959097
```

This is the sample code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
df2 <- group_by(df, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Ret2 = Ret1/100) %>% 
  mutate(annualreturn = rollapplyr(Ret2, width = 4, align = 'right',
                                   FUN = 'Return.annualized',
                                   scale = 4, geometric = TRUE, fill = NA))
```

I'm not sure why there is an error.

Comment: I am not getting any error, but the column annualreturn is all NA as there is only observation for each 'Date' (based on the example)

Comment: Yes, this error is not reproducible using your example.

Comment: `ungroup` your data frame before `rollapplyr`ing? Or make it >= `width` observations per group?